# Firebase. Error "Request contains an invalid argument."

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-admin

Use on backend side following libraries (from *package.json*).

```
"firebase": "^8.3.3",
"firebase-admin": "^9.6.0",
```

Try to send multicast message to multiple users.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const createNotificationMessage = (tokens: string[], data?: { [key: string]: string }): admin.messaging.MulticastMessage => {
  return {
    data,
    tokens,
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          contentAvailable: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };
};

const sendMulticast = (payload: admin.messaging.MulticastMessage) =>
  admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload);

const sendNotifications = async () => {
try {
      const data = getData(); // here we get main data
      const userTokens = getTokens(); // here we get tokens
      await sendMulticast(createNotificationMessage(userTokens, data));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
   }
```

I put 4 tokens to message before sending. But I got this error message in response

```
[{"success":false,"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-argument","message":"Request contains an invalid argument."}},{"success":false,"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-argument","message":"Request contains an invalid argument."}},{"success":false,"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-argument","message":"Request contains an invalid argument."}},{"success":false,"error":{"code":"messaging/invalid-argument","message":"Request contains an invalid argument."}}]
```

What I tried to do:

1. Send messages through method `send` one by one. Result: the same error on every message
2. Tried to set header `apns-priority` to 5. The same error
3. Tried to set custom properties in aps object - `content-available`, `content_available`. The same error
4. Delete `apns` property from payload. Works well and there is no errors but I need silent notifications in iOS applications that's why option `contentAvailable` is required.

One note: this code worked well till 9 April 2021.

Comment: I'm randomly receiving the same error as you, iOS only. If I repeat the exact same message, sometimes it fails, most of the times it doesn't. Inconsistency on receiving this error makes me think it may depend on the server instance that's receiving the request... just guessing. I'll leave your solution running for some days to see how it goes  :-/  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After full day search the reason of this errors, I found a solution for my problem.

```
const createNotificationMessage = (tokens: string[], data?: { [key: string]: string }): admin.messaging.MulticastMessage => {
  return {
    data,
    tokens,
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          contentAvailable: true,
          badge : 0
        },
      },
    },
  };
};
```

Don't know why `firebase` shows an error because according to official website, parameter `badge` is optional string.

Comment: Life saver thanks for your sacrifice, your solution helped me alot!